# Access microphone input from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I want to access the microphone input with `navigator.getUserMedia()`, but am unsure of how to proceed.

I can start the audio just fine, but I have no idea what to do with it after that.

```
if (!navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia 
                           || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia 
                           || navigator.mozGetUserMedia 
                           || navigator.msGetUserMedia;    
}

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, function (e) {
        // what goes here?
    }, function (e) {
        alert('Error capturing audio.');
    });
} else {
    alert('getUserMedia not supported in this browser.');
}
```

I would like to access it as a stream. I don't even need stereo, just a way to get the data.

**EDIT**: I want to send the data back to the server using websockets, to create a sort of intercom system. Here, i need to be able to access a simple audio stream, stopping and starting it on certain events.

Comment: https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs

Comment: I'm no expert on this, but I've been reading about the Web Real Time Communication project. http://www.webrtc.org/ and I found this hopefully helpful blog post: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: @HarveyA.Ramer I saw that html5rocks post, but it talked mostly about video.

Comment: It would be helpful to know exactly what you want to do. Are you trying to add effects? Record the audio? Analyze it?

Comment: @KevinEnnis I want to send it back to the server using websockets, to create a sort of intercom.

Comment: see answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27846392/access-microphone-from-a-browser-javascript

Answer (score 5):

If you mean you want access to the raw samples of the ongoing audio stream - use a ScriptProcessorNode in Web Audio (http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#ScriptProcessorNode).  RecordJS, mentioned above, will help show you how to do this.